# Suppressing certain Postgres logs

Tags: postgresql

I am running Postgres as Docker container (`postgres:15.0-alpine`) using `postgres -c log_statement=all -c log_destination=stderr` command to log **everything** (`all`) caused by my application. I am also using [pgAdmin 4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) as client UI. What I have been looking for is that, a way to suppress some logs (`LOG:  statement: /*pga4dash*/`) caused by pgAdmin. I have been reading Postgres [doc for logging](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-logging.html) but I couldn't find a solution. I am wondering if it is possible to suppress logs that look like below?

```
2023-10-19 16:14:27.154 UTC [55] LOG:  statement: /*pga4dash*/
    SELECT 'session_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Total",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'active' AND datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5))  AS "Active",
       (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity WHERE state = 'idle' AND datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5))  AS "Idle"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'tps_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) + sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Transactions",
       (SELECT sum(xact_commit) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Commits",
       (SELECT sum(xact_rollback) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Rollbacks"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ti_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_inserted) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Inserts",
       (SELECT sum(tup_updated) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Updates",
       (SELECT sum(tup_deleted) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Deletes"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'to_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(tup_fetched) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Fetched",
       (SELECT sum(tup_returned) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Returned"
    ) t
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'bio_stats' AS chart_name, pg_catalog.row_to_json(t) AS chart_data
    FROM (SELECT
       (SELECT sum(blks_read) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Reads",
       (SELECT sum(blks_hit) FROM pg_catalog.pg_stat_database WHERE datname = (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE oid = 5)) AS "Hits"
    ) t
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. At least not without writing PostgreSQL source code.

Answer (score 0):

If the pgAdmin4 dashboard doesn't help you, you could just turn it off.  That would prevent not just the logging, but also the running of those queries.

If you want to keep that dashboard, you could instead create a user just for use with pgAdmin4, and then countermand logging just for that user with `alter user pgadmin4_user set log_statement=mod`.  Of course that will also suppress logging of other statements coming in over those pgadmin4 connections, which might not be a problem (if pgAdmin4 is mostly used for monitoring or DDL) or might entirely defeat the purpose of having logging cranked up so high in the first place.

Of, you could just view the logs though some log-monitoring software that allows you to filter out the ones you don't want to see.  This might be easier if you change the log format to CSV.

Comment: `log_statement=mod` was an option until seeing that it doesn't log `SELECT` hence went for `all`. I think I will have to live with those noisy logs.

Comment: Not logging select, specifically for this user, was the point!